# Conditional group by in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

i have this simple query :

```
SELECT YEAR(P.DateCreated)
      ,MONTH(P.DateCreated)
      ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM   tbl1,
       tbl2....
GROUP BY
         MONTH(P.DateCreated)
        ,YEAR(P.DateCreated)
```

this will emit :

[image]

now i need the same query but with groupby **only** per year :

so :

```
SELECT YEAR(P.DateCreated)

      ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM   tbl1,
       tbl2....
GROUP BY
         YEAR(P.DateCreated)
```

i *dont* want to make 2 queries.

is there any way i can do conitional `group by` here ?

i can do with *one being replaced by another* , but i **cant** do *one being replaced by two*...

```
GROUP BY
     CASE WHEN @timeMode='y' THEN YEAR(P.DateCreated)
          WHEN @timeMode='m' THEN MONTH(P.DateCreated), YEAR(P.DateCreated) end
```

[image]

any help ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You would be better off with two separate queries but can do it like

```
GROUP BY YEAR(P.DateCreated),
       CASE 
          WHEN @timeMode='m' THEN MONTH(P.DateCreated) end
```

As `WHEN @timeMode <> 'm'` the second `GROUP BY` expression will be `NULL` for all rows and not affect the result.

Comment: so i must start from _smallest_ group by unit , and than expand it by case....riught ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. `CASE` can only return a single expression. This answers the question you actually asked.

Comment: does `group by myColumn,null,null` is valid ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - The order of the expressions in the `GROUP BY` doesn't make any difference. The important thing is that if you don't want to `GROUP BY` an expression then make sure it returns a constant value. IIRC SQL Server won't let you use an actual constant in the `GROUP BY` expression like that. I haven't got SSMS open to test at the moment

Comment: thanks man but still i have a question :  you cant use consts in group by ( like you said) but on the other hand , how will this `GROUP BY YEAR(P.DateCreated),
       CASE 
          WHEN @timeMode='m' THEN MONTH(P.DateCreated) end` can work ? if `@timeMode <>'m'` so what is the value there ? it is not null since groupby cant have null const inside of it...can you please explain ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - It is `NULL`. SQL Server doesn't prevent you from grouping by an expression that might return `NULL` it just prohibits expressions that don't reference the grouped by table(s) at all. `GROUP BY CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN myColumn ELSE NULL END` is valid even though it can only ever evaluate to `NULL`.

Comment: How cool. T-sql seems more dynamic than I expected if it can change the groupby at runtime. Also you need a similar case expression in the select list if you want to select the group key.

Answer (score 7):

You could use an `over` clause to return both the per-yearly and the per-month count in one query:

```
SELECT  distinct YEAR(P.DateCreated) as Year
,       MONTH(P.DateCreated) as Month
,       COUNT(*) over (partition by YEAR(P.DateCreated), MONTH(P.DateCreated)) 
            as MonthCount
,       COUNT(*) over (partition by YEAR(P.DateCreated)) as YearCount
FROM   YourTable P
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5fb1/5/0)

Comment: i dont see how it helps...  :) can you elaborate please

Comment: It would return both results.  If you'd like to toggle the query between two modes, see @MartinSmith's answer!